# How can I paste the "plain" text of a string to int? C#

Tags: c#, memory-address

I'm making an application which edits specific memory addresses of a process chosen by the user. I've to convert a string for example "0x7ffe0030,0x7ffe6000" to a list of strings and for every string in the list I've to paste the plain text of the string as int for example: if the string is "0x7ffe0030", the int must be 0x7ffe0030.

I've trivially tried to do that:

```
foreach (var address in addressListRaw)
{
 int a = Int32.Parse(address);
}
```

but it obviously doesn't work.

```
Console.WriteLine("Select the memory addresses to modify.\n" +
            "You can write more than one address separating\n" +
            "every address using the character ','\n" +
            "example: 0x7ffe0030,0x7ffe6000");


string addressesRaw = Console.ReadLine();
List<string> addressListRaw;
addressListRaw = addressesRaw.Split(',').ToList(); 
foreach (var address in addressListRaw)
{
 int a = Int32.Parse(address);
 Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To parse a `0x` prefixed hex literal you can use [Convert.ToInt32(String, Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=netframework-4.8#System_Convert_ToInt32_System_String_System_Int32_)

> Converts the string representation of a number in a specified base to
>   an equivalent 32-bit signed integer.

```
foreach (var address in addressListRaw)
{
     int intValue = Convert.ToInt32(prefixedHex , 16);
}
```